# Are there Logs for Add-in Error: A problem occurred while trying to reach this add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

Users of our OfficeJS Add-in occasionally receive the following error when opening the Add-in

A problem occurred while trying to reach this add-in

[Screenshot of the error in the Outlook Add-In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEOnH.png)

This error happens before any of our code is loaded (and even requested?) so we do not have a great way of debugging this error, and are having trouble reproducing since it is so intermittent.

Are there log files that Outlook can provide for add-in errors like the one above?

I have looked at the following but did not see anything relevant, not sure if i didnt look hard enough:

1. [Enable Runtime Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging) - it seems to only output logs relevant to the manifest.xml, not to errors happening runtime
2. Enabling logging from File -> Options -> Advanced: I couldnt find anything of value, although I do not know how to parse ETL files.
3. Using the "Get Diagnostics" tool in Outlook's Help Menu: It creates a zip with a bunch of files. But grepping around I did not see anything of value, and similarly i do not know how to parse the etl files

Comment: This error message is usually an indication of an HTTP request failure. Have you tried looking at Fiddler logs from the impacted customers to see if they contain any relevant information?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am working with the customer to set up fiddler. Do you have any advice on what I should be looking for? If my add-in html is https://example.com/inbox.html, are you suggesting that there would be a failure making the request to my url? Or should I be looking for some internal outlook request for failures?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You should be looking to a call to your add-in and any calls to Exchange if you use any APIs that call Exchange.